# MySQL Insert Query working on Localhost MySQL Database but not on online MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

include 'includes/session.php';

if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $repassword = $_POST['repassword'];

    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $lastname;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

    if ($password != $repassword) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Passwords did not match';
        header('location: signup.php');
    } else {
        $conn = $pdo->open();

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM users WHERE email=:email");
        $stmt->execute(['email' => $email]);
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        if ($row['numrows'] > 0) {
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Email already taken';
            header('location: signup.php');
        } else {
            $now = date('Y-m-d');
            $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            //generate code
            $set = '123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            $code = substr(str_shuffle($set), 0, 12);

            try {
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, password, firstname, lastname, activate_code, created_on) VALUES (:email, :password, :firstname, :lastname, :code, :now)");
                $stmt->execute(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'firstname' => $firstname, 'lastname' => $lastname, 'code' => $code, 'now' => $now]);
                $userid = $conn->lastInsertId();

                $message = "
                        Registered!
                    ";

                //Load phpmailer
                require 'vendor/autoload.php';

                $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
                try {
                    //Server settings
                    $mail->isSMTP();
                    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                    $mail->Username = 'test@gmail.com';
                    $mail->Password = 'aaaaaa';
                    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                        'ssl' => array(
                            'verify_peer' => false,
                            'verify_peer_name' => false,
                            'allow_self_signed' => true
                        )
                    );
                    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
                    $mail->Port = 465;

                    $mail->setFrom('test@gmail.com');

                    //Recipients
                    $mail->addAddress($email);
                    $mail->addReplyTo('test@gmail.com');

                    //Content
                    $mail->isHTML(true);
                    $mail->Subject = 'ECommerce Site Sign Up';
                    $mail->Body    = $message;

                    $mail->send();

                    unset($_SESSION['firstname']);
                    unset($_SESSION['lastname']);
                    unset($_SESSION['email']);

                    $_SESSION['success'] = 'Account created. Check your email to activate.';
                    header('location: signup.php');
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                    header('location: signup.php');
                }
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $_SESSION['error'] = $e->getMessage();
                header('location: register.php');
            }

            $pdo->close();
        }
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Fill up signup form first';
    header('location: signup.php');
}

?>
```

The insert query is working normally on Local MySQL Database but when using it on an online Database it is not inserting any data.

Note that the email check query (if email is already used) is working normally on both local and online MySQL servers, the problem is only with the insert query.

There is no problem with db_conn.php file as it is normally doing other queries and logging in.

It is also sending normal emails using smtp...

Comment: If you're not getting an exception, then the `INSERT` query must be working. Have you tried printing all the variables to see if they contain the expected values?

Answer (score 1):

I had an almost identical issue just last week when moving some code from local over to online.

My issue ended up being because my online database as the SQL Mode contained "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES".

Check if that solves your problem. [Guide to remove STRICT mode here](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/17070/how-can-i-disable-mysql-strict-mode)

My exact steps to resolve were;

- Using phpMyAdmin navigate to 'Variables'
- Find "SQL Mode" and 'edit' the variable (while logged in as root)
- Remove "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES" but maintain all your existing config values

eg

```
sql_mode: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

becomes

```
sql_mode: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

NOTE: If you're going to disable this, you should ensure you perform your own data validation on all variables before performing queries using it.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause an exception to be signaled?

Comment: @Barmar Can depend on the config. In production, error reporting is usually disabled, and after tonnes of poking around this solved my issue completely with a new application that went live without impacting other apps that were running on the server in the same db too.

Comment: The code has `try/catch` around the query. That should catch the PDO excepton. It has nothing to do with PHP error reporting.

Comment: That's a fair point. I guess it should pick it up, although in my application MySQL wasnt even returning an error. If OP doesnt find this answer helpful, then we can delete it for future googlers :)

Comment: When trying to change the value it returns as it was before even after saving, any idea ?

Comment: @M.S what does the exception error return? Try printing it to the screen to see?